# BigQuery append data from csv to column

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, sql-update

I have a BigQuery table where I added a new column and am not sure as to how I can append data to its row.

This is the BigQuery table:

[image]

This is the csv/excel file: I did try to upload the csv directly as a new table but had errors and am now trying to update the column named 'Max_Takeoff_kg', its the last column in the csv. How do I write a query within BigQuery to update the rows with the data in the csv in the last column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading your data only for this time, I'd recommend that you save your `XLS` as `CSV` and try to create a new table again.

Anyway, you can update your table using `BigQuery DML` as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-data)

Its important to remember that in your case, for this approach works correctly you must have a way to identify your rows uniquely.

Example:

```
UPDATE your_db.your_table
SET your_field = <value>
WHERE <condition_to_identify_row_uniquely>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: yes, changing to csv and uploading it via the google cloud storage seemed to do the trick!